# How to upload a captcha image to 2captcha C#

Tags: c#, multipart, 2captcha

I want to resolve a captcha, so I use 2captcha service, but I don't understand about posting request by multipart.

Multipart sample:

```
<form method="post" action="http://2captcha.com/in.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="method" value="post">
    Your key:
    <input type="text" name="key" value="YOUR_APIKEY">
    The CAPTCHA file:
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" value="download and get the ID">
</form>
```

Comment: What don't you understand? It will be hard for anyone to answer without a clearer statement of what your question is

Answer (score 1):

This is just a schematic view of the post request.
Your post data will look like this: 
`method=post&key=your_apikey&file=...`

I recommend to take a look at the base64 sample, then getting the captcha image as `byte []` and converting it to base64 with something like `Convert.ToBase64 (...)`.

You can use WebClient to submit post requests.